# disable one URL in apache when two URLs point to same IP

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, apache2

I have two https://www.noip.com/ domains, `domain1.noip.com` and `domain2.noip.com`, that point to the same IP.

I have an apache config file to serve up `domain1.noip.com` and it works. The problem is if I go to `domain2.noip.com` it also serves up the site.

I want to make it so `domain2.noip.com` doesn't work, as in it loads nothing. The desired effect is if I went to a bad URL/site like where the web browser shows 'This site can’t be reached.'

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin my@email.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/stuff
        ServerName domain1.noip.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "this site can't be reached" error in the browser is usually a DNS error or timeout/no service listening on the port. You won't be able to get that since you do have apache listening for domain1 on the same IP.

Your best option here is to create a new virtualhost entry for domain2 and have a blank HTML file or a "these are not the droids you are looking for" type page in the web root.

Comment: thank you! that answers my question. i might just put up a 301 code or something.